# Shared viewModel with assisted injection and hilt

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-hilt, assisted-inject

I have an activity. This activity is receiving some arguments.
At the moment, I'm able to create a `viewModel` with those parameters with assisted injection.

```
//activity code
private val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels {   
    val keyName = intent.extras?.getString(KEY_NAME).orEmpty()
    ViewModel.provideFactory(keyName)
}
```

Now, I have a `navHostFragment` and all the fragments in the nav graph will use the viewModel I created before in the activity.
But I can't find a way share that viewModel

I already know we can use `activityViewModels` to share the viewModel with the activity

```
//fragment code
private val sharedViewModel: ViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

But my `sharedViewModel` doesn't have a constructor without assisted arguments (and fails in runtime).

At the moment, I have two solutions

**First option**: "create" a new viewModel in each fragment and receive the arguments from the activity (or navArgs) using activityViewModels to share the same instance (I didn't like this approach, but works)

```
private val viewModel: ViewModel by activityViewModels {   
    val keyName = navArgs.keyName
    ViewModel.provideFactory(keyName)
}
```

**Second option**: Remove the assisted arguments from the constructor and create a method in the viewModel to set the information I need:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository,
    .....
) : ViewModel() {

   fun setKeyName(keyName: String)....
```

So, my question is... is there a way to create a viewModel in the activity, with assisted arguments, and share that viewModel with the fragments?

Comment: So you have an activity that is responsible for creating a ViewModel from the intent extras and you want to give your fragments access to that same ViewModel (still using the intent extras as the key name)? Or are you trying to mix the activity scope with arguments sent only to a single fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I want to share the same viewModel with the all the fragments in the navGraph. My viewModel is like ... a DetailsViewModel. So, some basic information from the viewModel will be displayed into the user (using data binding) in all the fragments, and I'm retrieving the information in the viewModel init section

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. Where do the arguments come from? Are they purely from the activity intent extras?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, yes, currently my arguments came from the intent extras

Comment: Then `by activityViewModels()` (using `@HiltViewModel` and no custom factory) and `SavedStateHandle`, as Amjad mentioned in his answer, does this assisted injection of arguments automatically.

Comment: @ianhanniballake seems to be a good approach, but if I'll work with navArgs (or passing as an argument the information to the next fragment), that means I need to pass all my "injected" arguements in the navigation action, right?

Comment: If you already have the arguments at the activity level, then you shouldn't create a second source of truth (and a doubling of your impact on saved instance state) by also passing them around as arguments, that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With hilt library now supports view model which takes `SavedStateHandle` as parameter and values are passed with `SavedStateHandle` automatically. All you have to do is receive the value in the following way

```
@HiltViewModel
class ViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository, savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

init {

        // Use the same argName as in your navigation graph
        val name : String = savedStateHandle["keyName"]
        
    }
```

Comment: That feature certainly does not require Safe Args; it works for any Activity, Fragment, or Navigation destination's arguments automatically, whether you use Safe Args or not. Navigation 2.4 does offer a convenience method of `YourArgs.fromSavedStateHandle()` if you don't want to remember what your `"keyName"` is, but even that isn't necessary, just convenient :)

Comment: @ianhanniballake this is good . The answer has been updated :)